# Laravel - Why EventServiceProvider extends itself?

Tags: php, laravel, event-listener

My EventServisProvider is

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
```

I am using Laravel 7 and I noticed that:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
```

as default.
And

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

which means EventServiceProvider extends itself.

What is the logic here.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Please explain it as I am 5.

Comment: If that is **your own** class, why did you write it that way in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its extend another event provider because Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider is an abstraction on how to handle event in laravel application, extending it allow user to modify or override default implementation. but at the end of the day, Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider still extend Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider